# Server Worklight Development Server was unable to start within 60 seconds 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

After installing the testing framework for Worklight, I get the following error when I try to start the worklight development server.  "Server Worklight Development Server was unable to start within 60 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor."  Where do I increase this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to find why you are getting the error. But still i found a way to increase the timeout limit for worklight server start operation.
Open Worklight Development server wizard (By double clicking the worklight development server under servers view, you can open this), in that wizard you can see Timeouts for start and stop operation of worklight server.
Try to increase this timeout.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a fairly decent machine, but I also have a number of items running on it, including PGP, which slows down everything.

Answer (score 0):

If the worklight server has too many applications deployed, it takes time to start.

Another way could also be, remove the applications from server in Eclipse "Servers" view, and start it(so that time is reduced).

Once it is started, you can now deploy the adaptets/application back.